# Angular http: prevent calling multiple requests by chaining them

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have an API PUT to `/api` that I want to prevent sending multiple requests at the same time by chaining them: the second call should wait for the first one finish, and so on. No call should be ignored (I don't talk about throttle / debounce / rate limite).

For now, the only solution I came up with is with `Promise`

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApiService {
  private lastCall: Promise<null> = Promise.resolve(null);
  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient}

  async update(data: Data): Promise<null> {
    this.lastCall = this.lastCall.finally(() =>
      this.httpClient.put<null>('/api', data).toPromise(),
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better solution with **rxjs** such as `concatMap` operator using in ngrx effect, but I want to achieve it in service level:

```js
  update$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(updateAction),
    concatMap(action => this.api.update(...)),
  ));
```

Comment: you already have the answer

Comment: I'm interested in a solution with `Observable` only without converting to / returning `Promise` because I can't find anything after 1 hour of reflection.

Comment: Why don't you just return `this.httpClient.put<null>('/api', data)` inside `update(...)`?

Comment: Because I want the behavior in ApiService level, not at effect level, because the API is used at several locations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Subject` to emit your http request. Create an Observable that flattens this Subject with `concatAll`. Subscribe to it in your service.

You can append an Observer to your http request with `tap`.

```ts
import { Subject, Observable, PartialObserver } from "rxjs";
import { concatAll, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApiService {
  private requests = new Subject<Observable<any>>();
  private update$ = this.requests.pipe(concatAll());

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.update$.subscribe()
  }

  update(data: Data, observer: PartialObserver<any> = { complete: () => null }) {
    this.requests.next(
      this.httpClient.put<any>('/api', data).pipe(tap(observer))
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Caller to `update` method shoud be able to add callbacks when a request is ended

Comment: @htn I updated my answer so you can pass in an `Observer`.

Comment: I did not try it but I think it works. However, it is more complex than my Promise solution without any benefit. By using `Promise` instead of `Observable`, we lost the ability for caller to: 1. decide when to subscribe, 2. apply operators for `Observable` before subscribing. We can't do any of these with your solution.